# How to decode bit mask in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, bitmask

For example `10 = 2+8 = 2^1 + 2^3`

In the query, How can I select it when I want the code contains `2^1 or 2^3`?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and we can take a look.

Comment: I couldn't help it... I wanted to know too so I looked it up. Try using the bitwise and. If you take the field and use a bitwise and with the number you are looking for, and the result equals the number you are looking for, then the bit is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
where (10 & (1 << 1) ) > 0 or  (10 & (1 << 3)) > 0
```

Or, as a single operator:

```
where 10 & ( (1 << 1) | (1 << 3) ) > 0
```